# Changing Stata scientific notation to display whole number

Tags: stata, data-wrangling

I am trying to `drop` a specific observation with the code below:

```
drop if (importus==6.4e+06 & country =="Congo, Dem. Rep.")
```

The code produces no errors but it is not dropping the observation due to the scientific notation and it works with smaller numbers as in:

```
drop if (importus==75990 & country =="Chad")
```

Is there a way in Stata to convert all numeric variables to display more numbers as opposed to scientific notation?

Comment: Without a data example, the assumption that the data in question are "whole numbers" (integers) isn't self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer to the question is to use `format` to change the display format. It is quite rare that all numeric variables are best displayed with the same format.

The display format is, however, a side-issue to your question. If and only if the value in question is 6400000 then `drop if importus==6.4e+06` or `drop if importus==6400000` should both work (setting aside the other condition).

If the `drop` doesn't work as you expect, the likely explanation is that the value in question is not 6400000, but something close. Now the format may be pertinent. A sensible format for your variable depends on its resolution. If it is integer-valued then

```
. format importus %12.0f
```

is the kind of command you could try before using say `edit` or `list` to inspect the data. `help format` leads to more information.

As a matter of good practice in an audit trail, a value being 6400000 (or whatever it is exactly) is not an obvious reason why an observation should be `drop`ped. There could be (should be?) a better or more obvious reason why it should be `drop`ped which would make for clearer syntax.